# JavaFX java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.Label field sample.Controller.location to java.net.URL

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My JavaFX application has a Label with an fx:id of `location`. It is defined in an FXML file. When I try to run the application, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.Label field sample.Controller.location to java.net.URL

I am using JDK 12 with JavaFX 11.0.2.

I've seen other answers here on SO that say this is caused by a conflicting type for the `location` Label. For example, it might be declared as a Label in the FXML file but in the Java code it is something else (in this case, java.net.URL). However, as you can see in the code below, I am not using the URL class anywhere.

Changing the fx:id to something else (such as `loc`) makes the error go away, so `location` must be a "magic" name.

What is causing this?

#### sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="location" layoutX="133.0" layoutY="146.0" text="Output" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

#### Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

#### Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller
{
    @FXML
    Label location;

}
```

#### module-info.java

```
module MyTest
{
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    opens sample;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is relatively easy to find out by inspecting [`FXMLLoader`](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/modules/javafx.fxml/src/main/java/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.java):

```
/**
 * A key for location URL in namespace map.
 * @see #getNamespace()
 * @since JavaFX 2.2
 */
public static final String LOCATION_KEY = "location";
/**
 * A key for ResourceBundle in namespace map.
 * @see #getNamespace()
 * @since JavaFX 2.2
 */
public static final String RESOURCES_KEY = "resources";

private URL location;
private ResourceBundle resources;

private <T> T loadImpl(InputStream inputStream,
                       Class<?> callerClass) throws IOException {
    ...
    namespace.put(LOCATION_KEY, location);
    namespace.put(RESOURCES_KEY, resources);
    ...
}
```

Basically this means that `location` (like `resources`, `controller` and `Controller`) is a *reserved keyword*.

These keywords are added to a `namespace` (an observable map:  `ObservableMap<String, Object> namespace`), and `location` is the URL of the FXML file, something like:

```
namespace.put("location", "file:/path/to/your/FXML/file");
```

Later on, the different `fx:id` tags of your FXML file are evaluated and added to the same namespace:

```
private void processValue() throws LoadException {
    ...
    if (fx_id != null) {
        namespace.put(fx_id, value);
        injectFields(fx_id, value);
    }
    ...
}
```

In this case, if your `fx:id` is `"location"`, you will be doing something like:

```
namespace.put("location", Label@12dafafa);
```

Obviously, since you are using the same key, you are overwriting the former URL with a new object, in this case a Label.

Later on, when FXMLLoader tries to inject this location:

```
injectFields(LOCATION_KEY, location);
```

the exception happens, as the `Label` that the map gets from the key `"location"` can be set to the URL field:

```
Can not set javafx.scene.control.Label field org.openjfx.FXMLController.location to java.net.URL
```

While it is not documented, this means that you can't use `"location"` (nor `"resources"`, `"controller"`) as a value for the `fx:id` tag, because it will collide with these keywords.

Comment: Well, it'd be nice if the Scene Builder program would tell you that. The error message isn't helpful at all. Thanks!